# Improve the frequency of Current Source Howland effect Op-Amp

Tags: operational-amplifier, current-source, high-frequency, frequency-response

I need help on a Howland Effect circuit with a current source purpose with an output of 600mA and a constant gain throughout a range of frequencies starting in 0Hz to 1Mhz. I am currently using an OPA564 with 17 Mhz response but my cutoff frequency is around 87kHz. 
[image]
[image]
Figure 2 represents the Gain and Phase resulting of the circuit shown in figure 1 with the OPA564 Op-Amp with a +/- 6,2 V supply and the current limit flag of 10 kOhm.
So my question is how can I improve the performance to get the response with a dropoff only after 1MHz?

Comment: Have you seen this TI app note? [AN-1515: A Comprehensive Study of the Howland Current Pump](http://www.ti.com/lit/an/snoa474a/snoa474a.pdf). Section 4, Dynamics, and appendix D seem pertinent.